# LabelRenderer issue While Tap ReadMore... text not wordwrap in ios only

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uilabel, multiline, multilinestring

We are list comments showing Label initially it shows single line while tap that multipleline showing its requirement and also working as expected in Android but ios not working. While tap the ReadMore not working seems to issue in Labelrenderer

```
 protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (Control != null && Element != null)
            {
                var previous = UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls;
                UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Text))
                    Control.Text = Element.Text;
                UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = previous;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (Element.LineBreakMode == LineBreakMode.TailTruncation)
                {
                    Control.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false; 
                    Control.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation; 
                }
            }
        }
```

Is anything missing  Labelrenderer to add in IOS? Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you can set the **maxline**  property in xamarin.forms, set it as 1 when the label is shown in the beginning and 10 after you tapped it.like

```
   <Label x:Name="mylabel" Text="This is a really long long text,This is a really long long text,This is a really long long text,This is a really long long text"
                   WidthRequest="100"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   MaxLines="1">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onTapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
```

codebehind:

```
   private void onTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                mylabel.MaxLines = 10;
            }
```

Comment: Label text has been added dynamically we can't predict how many text has added, so how can we set MaxLines and is anything achieved renderer.

Comment: if  your text has 2 line and maxline is 3 , it won't change the size of label, it will still display 2 line. so you can set the maxline as big as you want.